# System.IO.FileNotFoundException after changing TargetFramework to net6.0 while using assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have a project A that in its csproj has TargetFramework set to net48 and uses a local dll from another project B for an assembly reference. If I build both of the projects and run the app A it works correctly, and the bin folder contains every dll for Nuget packages the project B needs.
When I change TargetFramework of both of the projects to net6.0 and build them, the bin folder of the project A doesn't contain the needed dlls anymore, and if i run the app A it stops with the exception: "System.IO.FileNotFoundExceptionn: Could not load file or assembly".

Here's an example of what the project A's csproj looked like before:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <RootNamespace>ProjectA</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ProjectB">
        <HintPath>..\..\SolutionB\ProjectB\bin\Release\ProjectB.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

And here's how it looks after switching to net6.0 (I'm including other minor changes in case it turns out to be important):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <RootNamespace>ProjectA</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="ProjectB">
        <HintPath>..\..\SolutionB\ProjectB\bin\Release\net6.0\ProjectB.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I couldn't find the answer for why it behaves differently and what is needed to achieve the same behaviour as before, if it's even possible. If not then what is the best way to reference another project's assembly? Would really appreciate the help on this.

Comment: the example shown can be found here: https://github.com/suseal4kontur/net6test

Comment: Try to find an answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/

Comment: What file exactly is the System.IO.FileNotFoundException about? (The exception message itself should tell which file could not be found) Don't guess intuitively which file it is...

Comment: Are you building via a solution file? If so, have you set the dependencies via `Project | Project Dependencies...` ?

Comment: @KęstutisRamulionis can't find the answer there... they describe the steps for migration, but i can't find a relevant one to this problem or a description of the change that causes it...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace it's about the assembly for a Nuget package that the project B references. so in the example above it's Automapper

Comment: @MatthewWatson i build it in IDE or with dotnet build, from sln or csproj - same results. doesn't <Reference Include...> in csproj set the dependency you're talking about? i'm a bit confused...

Comment: For a Solution, the project dependency setting goes in the .SLN file, and it defines the order in which to build the projects in the solution. So for example if you have project A and project B in a solution, where B references the build output from A, setting the dependency ensures that A is built before B. However, note that if you're using project references (where the reference refers to a ".csproj" rather than a ".dll" file)  then this is handled automatically.

Comment: @MatthewWatson oh. they are in two different solutions, and i manually (or with some other tools) build project B first